# Why is there no glow with the emission shader added?

Tags: animation, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I added keyframes but when I played the animation the emission shader doesn't seem to work. The object in the screenshot is supposed to flash.

[image]

Comment: Use drivers for that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all turn up the strength of the emission shader. In the screen shot the color is being animated but the strength is zero. This will most probably solve your problem . Also turn on bloom in the eevee settings for better glow in eevee.